# Invoke из другого класса

Tags: c#, vb.net

Я зыпускаю  Player() , она запускает prg1 в неовом потоке , а prg1 запускает test(). Всё работает без ошибок , `НО на экране ничего не происходит ! А без нового потока - всё работает правильно`

```
    Class Cls
        Public Shared Sub Player()
             Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf prg1)
        End Sub

        Private Shared Sub prg1()
             test()
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub test()
             Form1.PB.Top = 100
             Form1.PB.Left = 100
             Form1.PB.Visible = True
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Во-первых, что вы реально хотите сделать?**

> Уверен, что идея менять свойство `PictureBox1.Visible` из другого потока пришла не от хорошей жизни :)

- Далее, судя по всему, вы не очень понимаете концепцию делегатов в `.NET` и механизмов `Invoke / BeginInvoke`.

> `ThreadStart` - это *делегат,* и сам по себе он не имеет ничего общего с работой в другом потоке.

- Дальше вы *понадеялись* на то, что код, который вы написали будет делать то, что вы хотите.

> - К сожалению, написанный вами код практически (за исключением некоторых тонкостей, связанных с работой `Invoke`) эквивалентен простому вызову `test()` из этого же самого потока.
> - Это так, поскольку `Invoke` выполняет операцию в том же самом потоке, где создан контрол, то есть, в вашем случае, просто в `UI` потоке.

- Возвращаемая ошибка связана с тем, что, собственно, объект `Form1 : Control` в момент вызова `test()` еще не создан на уровне `WinAPI` или, наоборот, уже не существует, поскольку в таком случае механизм диспатчинга `Invoke / BeginInvoke` для него не имеет смысла.
- В подтверждение предыдущего высказывания рассмотрим следующий `snippet`:

  ```
      var form1 = new Form1();
      // Если убрать 'form1.Show()', то это приведет к
      // ошибке, аналогичной той, которая указана у вас в вопросе.
      form1.Show();
      form1.Invoke(new Action(() => { form1.Text = "Some new text"; }));
  ```
- А теперь - самое вкусное. Механизм `Invoke / BeginInvoke`, вообще говоря, предназначен для ситуации, диаметрально противоположной той, которую вы описали в вашем вопросе.

> - То есть, его основная задача заключается в том, чтобы дать пользователю возможность обновить состояние `UI` **из другого потока.**
> - Грубо говоря, у вас может быть какой-нибудь `Worker Thread,` которому необходимо обновить `UI` в некоторый момент времени (это антипаттерн, однако в качестве примера сойдет).
> - В таком случае из кода, который работает в `Worker Thread` вы можете обратиться к контролу, созданному в другом потоке и совершить какие-либо действия с помощью `Invoke / BeginInvoke.` Попытка же совершить действия по обновлению `UI` напрямую из другого потока сфейлится, поскольку это не предусмотрено в `WinAPI` и, как следствие, в `Windows.Forms`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать я выполняю Form1.Invoke(New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf test)) из процедуры вызванной в новом потоке

Comment: @dizar47 В таком случае стоило точнее отразить это в вопросе, а также см. середину ответа.